# Java: Import CSV problem with leading zero

Tags: java, csv

I'm trying to import csv file, but leading zeros makes me problem.

Structure of CSV:

```
code1 | code2 | code3
-----------------------
00101 | 00021 | 0589654
00101 | 00022 | 0589654
00101 | 00023 | 0589654
00101 | 00024 | 0589654
```

Here is my code for reading CSV:

```
private static List<Code> readCodesFromCSV(String fileName) {
        List<Code> codes = new ArrayList<>();
        Path pathToFile = Paths.get(fileName);

        // create an instance of BufferedReader
        // using try with resource, Java 7 feature to close resources
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile)) {

            // read the first line from the text file
            String line = br.readLine();

            // loop until all lines are read
            while (line != null) {

                // use string.split to load a string array with the values from
                // each line of
                // the file, using a comma as the delimiter
                String[] attributes = line.split(",");

                Code code = createCode(attributes);

                // adding book into ArrayList
                codes.add(code);

                // read next line before looping
                // if end of file reached, line would be null
                line = br.readLine();
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return codes;
    }

    private static Code createCode(String[] metadata) {
        String code = "\"\t" + metadata[0] + "\"" + "\"\t" + metadata[1] + "\"" + "\"\t" + metadata[2] + "\"";
        //String code = metadata[0] + metadata[1] + metadata[2];;


        // create and return code of this metadata
        return new Code(code);
    }
```

I need to join all 3 codes into one, but the problem are leading zeros. When i import file and get merged code i get code without leading zeros, so i try with adding \t but it doesn't help.
Does anyone know how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Simplest logic will be read the file with readLine option, skip first two lines. Get the contents, replace pipe (|), then replace space.

Comment: Where are you getting values without zeros? In Codes? In which datatype they are stored, if its being stored as numbered datatype - int / float / double, it will never start with zero, then probably only way will be to store it as string
So question is , what is doing this `Code code = createCode(attributes);`

Comment: Your code does not lose zeroes. I'm pretty sure there are no zeroes in CSV file. Can you check its content in text editor?

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx The answer to your question is just below, where that function is specified.  However, it leads to a further question, what is `new Code(code)` doing? (Parsing integers?)  Also, a sample of the actual CSV would be helpful instead of / in addition to the pipe-separated table above, including for clarity that the CSV actually does have the leading 0s.

Comment: @WBT hey! thanks, I completely missed it, yes, then the right question is what `New Code(code)` is doing, thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: remark, `Code` is not standard JDK class, neither in [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/allclasses-noframe.html) neither in [Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/allclasses-noframe.html), so its the custom code, then probably the issue came from there

Answer (score 2):

Would not be simpler to write a new constructor, that takes a `String[]` argument, instead of gluing the Strings together in some custom format to be parsed by the current constructor?

BTW your constructor would be called with a `String` like this:
(I left `\t` intact, all other characters are in the `String` value...)

```
"\t00101""\t00021""\t0589654"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just replace your Code datatype with String and once you have the correct codes List from each line, parse or convert it to whatever you want from there.

```
private static List<String> readCodesFromCSV(String fileName) throws IOException {
        List<String> codes = new ArrayList<>();
        Path pathToFile = Paths.get(fileName);

        // create an instance of BufferedReader
        // using try with resource, Java 7 feature to close resources
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile)) {

            // read the first line from the text file
            String line = br.readLine();

            // loop until all lines are read
            while (line != null) {

                // use string.split to load a string array with the values from
                // each line of
                // the file, using a comma as the delimiter
                String[] attributes = line.split(",");

                String code = createCode(attributes);

                // adding book into ArrayList
                codes.add(code);

                // read next line before looping
                // if end of file reached, line would be null
                line = br.readLine();
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return codes;
    }

    private static String createCode(String[] metadata) {
        String code = metadata[0] + metadata[1] + metadata[2];
        return code;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, its not clear from the code, what is happening in the `Code` constructor, but assuming there is the issue,

> in parsing values with **leading zeroes** to some numbered datatype, check bellow example of parsing `String (with leading zero) into int` datatype:

Code is `taking String array` with values with leading zeroes and `parsing into String with separator`, second method parse the same array `into int` by [Integer.parseInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

```
public static void testMe() {
    String[] testData = {"00101","00021","0589654","00101","00022"};
    System.out.println("INPUT: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < testData.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(testData[i] + ",");
    }

    System.out.println("\n");
    String stringData = loadStringArrayToString(testData);
    System.out.println("check, its parsed with leading zeros: \n" + stringData +"\n");

    int[] intData = loadStringArrayToIntArray(testData);
    System.out.println("check, zeros are gone (because integer as datatype):");
    for (int i = 0; i < intData.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(intData[i] + ", ");
    }

}


public static String loadStringArrayToString(String[] inputData) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char separator = ';';

    // -1 to avoid last separator
    for (int i = 0; i < inputData.length -1; i++) {
        sb.append(inputData[i]);
        sb.append(separator);
    }
    sb.append(inputData[inputData.length-1]);

    return sb.toString();
}

public static int[] loadStringArrayToIntArray(String[] inData) {
    int[] retData = new int[inData.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < inData.length; i++) {
        retData[i] = Integer.parseInt(inData[i]);
    }

    return retData;
}
```

Output is:

```
INPUT: 
00101,00021,0589654,00101,00022,

check, its parsed with leading zeros: 
00101;00021;0589654;00101;00022

check, zeros are gone (because integer as datatype):
101, 21, 589654, 101, 22,
```